# problem on array comparison due to json conversion

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I have a problem comparing to arrays, in fact I don't think that my method is wrong but a problem occurs during the formatting steps I use and I don't understand why.
here is my process : I have to arrays

```
log.info "get  " +get_conditions["configuration"]
log.info "ref  " +ref_conditions["configuration"]
log.info "get class : " +get_conditions["configuration"].class
log.info "ref class : " +ref_conditions["configuration"].class
// which gives
INFO: get  [[uid:fim:automation:Variable:280, value:0, operator:!=]]
INFO: ref  [[uid:fim:automation:Variable:280, operator:!=, value:0]]
INFO: get class : class java.util.ArrayList
INFO: ref class : class java.util.ArrayList
```

comparing straightforward does not work
so, what I do to be able to compare those two unordered lists is to format them as json

```
get= groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(get_conditions["configuration"])
ref= groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(ref_conditions["configuration"])
// which gives 
[{"uid":"fim:automation:Variable:280","value":"0","operator":"!="}]
[{"uid":"fim:automation:Variable:280","operator":"!=","value":0}] ==> here is the failing point
```

on the second conversion, the 0 is without quotes !? this prevents equality to occur.

does anyone has any idea of why a similar process on similar type of data can produce such a difference ?

I must have missed something, this is very annoying as comparison would be straightforward with this method

thank you

Comment: One is a number, the other is a string. You need to identify where the difference in data types comes from.

Comment: you can not compare int to string without type casting

Comment: indeed .. i'll check why my input data has different types, it should'nt. Thanks for your help